# How to simulate mouse over event on a div using enzyme for testing a react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a div that `onMouseOver` and `onMouseLeave` toggles a child div as a dropdown. I want to test the hover event using enzyme.

The relevant code for the component is:

```
<div className="search-category" onMouseOver={() => toggleDropdown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => toggleDropdown(false)}>
    <div className="search-type">
        ...
    </div>
    {dropdownShown && <SearchMenu searchSections={searchSections} dispatch={dispatch} />}
</div>
```

The relevant test code is

```
...
it('should toggle search type dropdown on mouse hover', () => {
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.SearchMenu').exists()).toEqual(false);
    enzymeWrapper.find('.search-category').simulate('mouseOver');
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.SearchMenu').exists()).toEqual(true);
});
...
```

`.SearchMenu` is the className of the `SearchMenu` component.

`toggleDropdown` is a simple function that toggles the `dropdownShown` flag.

The issue i'm facing is that even after calling `.simulate`, the `expect` on the last line returns `false` when it should return `true`. The code is working perfectly as I can see the dropdown on the browser and in the element tab of the browser.

Please let me know if any more details are required.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to call `enzymeWrapper.update()`, http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html

Comment: just tried it. still not working.
when I try to console `enzymeWrapper.find('.search-category').debug()`, it still prints the html without the `SearchMenu` component. :/

Comment: Is the help needed still?

Comment: yes, please! @ChasingUnicorn

Answer (score 16):

If I have replicated your issue correctly, here is the [**working demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3zjj9rp1l), of the test cases you were trying to run. I have written a number of test cases using enzyme and jest, and I think this is the right way to do the testing. :)

**Toggle.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const SearchMenu = () => <input />;

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  state = { dropdownShown: true };

  toggleDropdown = value => {
    this.setState({ dropdownShown: value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="search-type"
        onMouseOver={() => this.toggleDropdown(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.toggleDropdown(false)}
      >
        <h1>Hover over me to hide/unhide the input</h1>
        {this.state.dropdownShown && <SearchMenu />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Toggle;
```

**Toggle.spec.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Toggle from "./Toggle";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import { SearchMenu } from "./Toggle";

describe("Toggle Component", () => {
  it("check state", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Toggle />);
    expect(wrapper.find(<SearchMenu />).exists).toBeTruthy();

    // Testing Initial State
    expect(wrapper.state("dropdownShown")).toBe(true);
    wrapper.simulate("mouseleave");

    // Testing state after mouseleave
    expect(wrapper.state("dropdownShown")).toBe(false);

    // Testing state after mouseover
    wrapper.simulate("mouseover");
    expect(wrapper.state("dropdownShown")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've done almost the same thing as you. Actually I'm also using redux along with react and the component is a connected one, so the test code that I've written is a little different. It would be great if you could take a little time to look at the gist I've created containing the testing code. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/deepank411/4cdcaf2ab40ee6f76a5d9afd083f1224)

Answer (score 6):

Chasing Unicorn's answer above is almost perfect. Instead of passing `mouseover` to wrapper.simulate, it should be `mouseenter`.

This worked for me:

```
  it('sets hoveredOver state to true/fase from mouseenter and mouseleave events', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} />);

    // initial state:
    expect(wrapper.state('hoveredOver')).toBe(false);

    wrapper.simulate('mouseenter');
    expect(wrapper.state('hoveredOver')).toBe(true);

    wrapper.simulate('mouseleave');
    expect(wrapper.state('hoveredOver')).toBe(false);
  });
```

This is with Enzyme v3.3.0 in my `package.json`